# ADX's built in export command vs ADFv2 copy activity performance

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Kusto (ADX) has `.export` command to export data from Kusto to other data stores (Azure Storage is of my particular interest though). Here I am not referring to continuous export but rather just export command which can also be used in on-demand manner. I think couple of years back this was the only (out of the box) option to export data out of Kusto. Now I see that **ADFv2** (Azure Data Factory v2) **copy activity** also supports ADX (Kusto) as one of the sources and using this we are able to copy data from Kusto to Azure Storage. But which method is faster ? Is there any recommendation? One could also orchestrate .export command from ADFv2's ADX command activity which is what we were doing earlier -- but now I see that **copy activity** from ADFv2 has started supporting ADX as source out of the box , which is much easier to work with. But we only want to use the method which will provide best performance (faster).

Comment: Why don't you experiment and see and enlighten us all. Most likely they use an identical API, except that Kusto>ADF>Blob is most likely a cloud-only activity requiring no data round trip. Besides that you have the advantage of ADF managed identity substantially simplifying security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the comparison between copy activity and the export command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-integration#select-between-copy-and-azure-data-explorer-command-activities-when-copy-data) specifically the tip here:
[image]

The reason for it, is that the ".export" command perform better as it by default executed in parallel as well as providing more customization options.